# Same name resources conflict from different libraries

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have multiple third party libraries added in my application.
I am using some resources for ex: *R.drawable.ic_logo* and want to reference that icon from one of the added libraries.

But, it always takes the icon from my app's local resources, since there is same name *ic_logo* resource in my app.

How to fix this?

Comment: reftractor the local resource name than the global

Comment: Without changing the names, is it possible

Comment: you can mention the parent class before the R like android.R

Comment: or parent package name

Comment: Even tried that, like com.package.name.R.drawable.ic_logo but it still takes the icon from the local app resources

Answer (score 2):

You can't fix this without renaming. For it is a designed behavior.

Android Studio > User guide: Create an Android library: [Development considerations for library modules](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#Considerations)

> **Resource merge conflicts**
>
> The build tools merge resources from a library module with those of a
> dependent app module. *If a given resource ID is defined in both
> modules, the resource from the app is used.*

The only workaround is to rename the resource file in your app module to avoid conflict.

Comment: To avoid resource conflicts, use non-transitive (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build#use-non-transitive-r-classes) R classes. If this is not possible, then consider using a prefix or other consistent naming scheme that is unique to the module (or is unique across all project modules)

Comment: eventually, non-transitive R classes is not working for me. I've filed an issue, you can track status here :  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/297805133